# How do I concatenate a string to an int*?

Tags: c#, pointers, unsafe

I am practicing using pointers in C# (via unsafe code). So now, I just want to concatenate "" to an int*, so I can use it as a parameter in `Console.WriteLine()`.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        fullOfPointers();
    }
    static unsafe void fullOfPointers()
    {
        int value = 10;
        int* adress = &value;
        Console.WriteLine(&value+"");//error
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

But the compiler says that operator '+' cannot be used on int* and string. So what should I do?

Comment: You're trying to deal with pointers when you don't understand basic C# types? Maybe you meant to concatenate in the opposite direction?

Comment: What basics do I not understand?

Comment: Primarily that a string is not numeric and can't be added to an int, but an int can be concatenated to a string, which is the reverse of what you've done. Just the concept of reference types vs value types makes trying to attach a string to an int strange.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the memory address of the pointer.. cast it to an `int`:

```
Console.WriteLine((int)&value); // will produce random memory address
```

If you want the value of `address`.. dereference the pointer:

```
Console.WriteLine(*address); // produces 10
```

I have absolutely no idea why you're trying to concatenate anything with a `string`.. it isn't necessary.

Comment: But Consolw.WriteLine() takes a string as a parameter.

Comment: It also takes an `int`... there is about 30+ overloads for it.

Answer (score 0):

`&value` returns value's `address`, you are trying to concatenate a memory address with a string literal.If you want to `adress's` value, you need to use `*address`, so you can try:

```
Console.WriteLine(*adress + "  asd");
```

The output will be:

```
10 asd
```